# What are all of the ways in which a character might be prevented from aging, or the equivalent of cryogenically frozen?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

I'm looking for the ways in which a character can be found in a state in which they have not aged since entering it, which could be several hundred years or millenia. This could be an effect such as being frozen somehow (becoming petrified or turned to stone would be an example, assuming it does not cause their death) as a result of a spell or creature interaction, or other methods such as capturing a soul in an object that can be found.

While this is for a 5th edition game, methods from previous editions are also pertinent.

Comment: In a word: magic

Comment: @DaleM Thanks. When my players ask how this person is still here, I'll just say "Magic".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because list questions are off-topic per [this meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176/23970).

Comment: Are you looking for lore explanations, or mechanical ones?

Comment: This would be a good question, but allowing solutions from other editions makes it way too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequester, Petrification, being trapped on a variable time plane (Feywild comes to mind if you use the book version, or time on the Astral).

Mirror of Life Trapping works pretty well too.

Petrification admittedly has its problems if millennia are involved given that it would erode over time if not given proper shelter and care.

Sequester has the added caveat of allowing it to end at a specified time or event. Meaning that the first signs of a prophecy are starting to be fulfilled therefore this person is awakened from a bygone civilization or what not.

Simply saying "Magic" or "Reasons" always leaves a bad taste in my mouth but sometimes you do that at first then come of with the explanation later for the players that want to delve into the back story of that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Petrification is probably the easiest example, and there are a lot of monsters that can do that (basilisk, medusa, etc.)

I think the best example of what you're looking for is 3.5's psionic Crystallize power:

> In an eyeblink, the subject’s form seems to freeze over, as its flesh and fluids are instantly crystallized. Following the application of this power, the subject appears lifeless. In fact, it is not dead (though no life can be detected with powers or spells that detect such).

This requires another psion to come by and unfreeze the creature, if the original psion is no longer around.